# How to ignore a Class During a Click Function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have four divs that are setup as follows:

```
<div class="navmenu">
<div class="top-nav">
<div class="canvas">
<div class="notif">
```

As part of a click function, using jQuery, I do not want my .click function to trigger when the div class is in (navmenu,top-nav,notif), only when they click on the canvas class.

Click function would be something like this:

```
  $(".canvas").click(function() {
    alert('Hi I am bound to the canvas!');
  });
```

Comment: how is your click function registered?

Comment: if you can, add a common class to all those elements to which the click handler has to be added then use it to add the click handler...

Comment: Since your [recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27414528/4), your question is rather unclear. What is wrong with the jQuery you have posted?

Comment: are you asking how to ignore a click on a child element?

Answer (score 1):

*My original answer -- below -- applies to [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27414528/3) of the question.*

Use the following selector:

```
$("div[class^='my-class-']:not('.my-class-c')")
```

This gets `div` elements with a class that [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `my-class-`, and [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) elements with the class `my-class-c`.

Comment: What if I also wanted to ignore both my-class-c and my-class-d?

Comment: @tonsils `$("div[class^='my-class-']:not('.my-class-c,.my-class-d')")`

Comment: Sorry @Mooseman - had to rewrite my question above to reflect more what I am after. Would appreciate if you could please update your answer. Thanks.